# How to find what are the mobile devices currently available for testing in browserstack

Tags: node.js, appium, browserstack

I am trying to run my tests against browserstack but always get an environment not available error. My question is if there is a way to find the available environments so that I can use that in my test. Thanks.

Comment: Browse from you account in Products and Automate or App automate by case and you should find all the documentation you need there

Comment: Any code or anything? What were you trying to do?

Comment: @lauda comment lead me to find the devices available for my account. Thanks